# org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Could not resolve attribute 'dapil_id' of 'com.allobank.allobackendtest.entity.Caleg'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am a beginner in Spring Boot and I have a problem with my code.

I got the error like you can see on the picture. I have created a search/filter with query param, but the error said : `"Caused by: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Could not resolve attribute 'dapil_id' of 'com.allobank.allobackendtest.entity.Caleg'"`

Please help me, thank you.

[**My entity**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jpPE.png)